# Maximum amount of data stored in ASP.net session variables

Tags: asp.net, pdf, session-state, session-variables

I have a form where users can upload Pdf files(about 30 pages to one document or so). I want to delay storing these Pdfs in the database until the user submits the entire form. The problem is that the collection of files uploaded must be able to persist through postbacks. That being said, I am considering storing these as session variables, however, would this be too much data to store, or are session variables meant to store a couple strings here and there? If this method is not acceptable, is there an alternate method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a request for disaster.

Store them on disk or SQL as temp, and only store the path or id to them. As you said it yourself "session variables meant to store a couple strings here and there"

I think even path or id must be stored in database as well so that if your server recycles the session, you do not lose all that data and user could have it for a period of time until a timeout which you clear the files.

Comment: I would say that storing files on-disk on the webserver is even more disastrous than keeping them in memory. Text-only PDFs are reasonably small, and if he's working in a small system where the number of users is kept reasonably low, or where database access is prohibitively expensive, storing them in session may be the right answer.

Comment: @Mark What are the potential pit-falls of saving on-disk? It seems I'm in between a "disaster" and "even more disastorous".

Comment: In some situations (shared-hosting, for one example) you won't have access to a local disk on the webserver, or in a load-balanced scenario you might save some PDFs on one server, and others on another server, and your final all-done request might happen on a server where there are no PDFs at all saved on the disk. You should avoid any solution that uses persistent storage on the web server.

Comment: @Aliostad: depending on your definition of "scalable", storing things in memory is perfectly "scalable". It's all a matter of how and when you want to (or even if you will ever need to) "scale". If you're running a CPU-heavy web application, you might already have a low user-to-server ratio and using extra memory for session variables won't make a difference. There's not enough information in the question to make the assumptions you're making.

Comment: The user to server ratio will be pretty low, and this is not a shared-hosting situation.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of data you can store in session variables is limited only by amount of memory on your server(s) (if you're using a session persistence system that uses memory). You need to calculate how many concurrent users you want to serve on a machine, figure out how much memory you'll use per session, and figure out whether or not you've got enough.